# GitHub returns status code 403 while pushing new mvc project to repository

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, github, model-view-controller, github-for-windows

From my editor visual studio, I am trying to push MVC project to GitHub, I am  also logged into GitHub, every time when i try to push new project, it returns status code with 403.

> Error:
>
> unable to access 'https://github.com/saritapal108/WebApiDemo2/': The requested URL returned error: 403

What am i missing?
Please Help!

Comment: Same for me and i found solution is just create repo and don't add anything in repo even "readme" and just sync your code after commit this is always work for me

Comment: You have to push or commit your code on "https://github.com/dharmeshsharma/mybooks.git" like this. mean ".git" is must include in visual studio.

Comment: @Dharmeshsharma i already tried that method but doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps

1. New Repo in Github
   [image: Step1]
2. Just Copy this URL from next page 
   [image: Step1]
3. New Source Code in Visual Studio add to github source local only
   [image: Step3]
4. Select Team Explorer and select `Push to Remote Repository`
   [image: Step4]
5. Add Github Url 
   [image: Step5]
6. After Publish just click sync
   [image: Step6]
7. Finally your code in Repo.
   [image: Step7]

let me know in which step you facing issue.
Thanks
Dharmesh